# Importing a *.svg module raises Typescript error : "Cannot find module ..."

Tags: typescript, svg, vue.js

It's a web application made with `@vue/cli`.
I want to use `vue-svg-loader` to load inline Svg as vue components.

As [vue-svg-loader installation guide](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader#readme) says, I put this code in `vue.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');
    svgRule.uses.clear();
    svgRule
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader');
  },
};
```

and import my Svg file with `import ViwanMap from '@/assets/ViwanMap.svg';`.

Also, I created a `shims-svg.d.ts` in my `src/` folder containing :

```
import { VNode } from 'vue';
declare global {
  type Svg = VNode; // With vue-svg-loader, imported svg is a Vue component.
}

declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: Svg;
  export default content;
}
```

Also, there is my `tsconfig.js` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The compilation process raises this error :

```
ERROR in <MY_PROJECT_ROOT>/src/views/Home.vue
12:22 Cannot find module '@/assets/ViwanMap.svg'.
```

However, the webpack process seems to work, as the svg shows up in my app. It seems to be only a typescript issue. Do you know what is the problem ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Harshal Patil's answer worked, except I used what was here instead: [Official Documentation](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-this-loader-with-typescript)

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import Vue, {VueConstructor} from 'vue';
  const content: VueConstructor<Vue>;
  export default content;
}
```

Comment: I've put that in `shims-svg.d.ts` and it worked fine

Comment: I'm only able to get this to work with node ^17. LTS v16.5 causes failure.

Comment: I just added the updated code below.

Answer (score 8):

You need just little adjustment to your module declaration for `.svg` files. Your `shims-svg.d.ts` file should be:

```
declare module '*.svg' {

    import { VNode } from 'vue';

    // DON'T DECLARE THIS INSIDE GLOBAL MODULE
    type Svg = VNode;

    const content: Svg;
    export default content;
}
```

*Note that augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.*

Comment: It's okay :)
By the way, I confused `VNode` and `Vue` class. An imported svg with `vue-svg-loader` is a Vue class, not a VNode (instance of a Vue).

Comment: I used https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-this-loader-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I have a better version of *"svg.d.ts"* file for Vue.js that will fix the error and also **make it recognize the imported SVG as an actual `<svg>` element**:

```js
declare module '*.svg' {
  import type { SVGAttributes, DefineComponent } from 'vue';

  const content: DefineComponent<SVGAttributes>;
  export default content;
}
```