# Importing mp3 into Vue/TypeScript app results in 'Cannot find module' error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm attempting to import some .mp3 files into my Vue/Typescript app, but on 'npm run serve' I receive the following error:

```
ERROR in /Users/***/***/application/src/components/Sampler.vue(80,16):
80:16 Cannot find module '@/assets/samples/A1.mp3'.
    78 | import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    79 | import * as Tone from 'tone';
  > 80 | import A1 from '@/assets/samples/A1.mp3';
```

Note, the app still serves regardless and the media files play as expected, however it causes the production build to fail.

I had the same issue with some .svg file which I fixed thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937634/importing-a-svg-module-raises-typescript-error-cannot-find-module) by creating a `shims-svg.d.ts` file an inserting the following:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import Vue, {VueConstructor} from 'vue';
  const content: VueConstructor<Vue>;
  export default content;
}
```

I've tried adding a file for mp3s specifically with the same, swapping out '*.svg' with '*.mp3' but that didn't work.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250213/typescript-import-returns-cannot-find-module) have mentioned it could be an issue with specifying paths in tsconfig - but I don't see that as being the issue:

Mine is as follows:

```
"paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*",
        "./*"
      ]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this for other files?

Comment: How are you using the mp3 file, can you show the whole component? Do you also get an error if you want to import an asset other than .mp3?

Comment: Here is the link to the component: (https://github.com/Am4nzi/ac-vue/blob/master/src/components/Sampler.vue).

I'm using the Tone.js library to create the media interface which triggers the samples either on the click of a button, or on key presses. However, even if I remove all the code and leave just the imports, I still receive the error.

Comment: Yes, I get the error even if I'm importing a different file, for instance important a .wav file results in the same error.

Comment: Can you try adding by the relative path `../../..` and to see if error is reproducing?

Comment: Why would you want to import media files into your code like that, as opposed to loading them via HTTP or the file system (in the case of Node.js)? Even if it were possible (which I'm not sure it is), they can't be bundled up into a JS or CSS file, so how would they be output?

Comment: I have, and it makes no difference at all - the results remain the same (error appears in console, yet the functionality still works as intended i.e. I can play the mp3 file in the app).

Comment: @NilsonJacques I'm still relatively new to working with media files, would it be possible to link me to a resource which explains best practice using the methods you suggested? Good unfortunately hasn't been very helpful this time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this file that I use audio with vue https://github.com/onuriltan/NoteManager/blob/master/web/src/views/NotFoundView.vue

Comment: @Am4nzi Basically just treat them in the same way you would images or videos: upload them to a publicly accessible folder on a web server, and link to them via a URL in your code.

Comment: @NilsonJacques Ah, that doesn't work. If I try that method it doesn't play at all, I think it has something to do with Vue itself. The way I'm doing it is how it's recommended by the Tone.js devs if you're using Vue: (https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Using-Tone.js-with-React-or-Vue)

Comment: @onuriltan That would work if I was using the built-in HTML5 audio tools, but in my case I have to use tone.js for the project I'm working on, and the files have to be referenced in the JS code, not the markup.

Comment: @Am4nzi Oh, my bad.. I didn't realise it was possible. I noticed that you linked your repo above, so I cloned it and it actually builds fine for me, with no errors.

Comment: Thanks @NilsonJacques - very kind of you to go to that much effort! It could be my ESLint overreacting. As I mentioned on my side the app works fine without the errors. I'll just disable those lines and hope for the best!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the comments, it's probably due to ESLint being overly sensitive. I'll disable these rules and go from there.